# Braintree's payment_method_nonse is empty when trying to post data to server

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5, payment, braintree

I'm trying to set up DROP-IN UI. I'm  using Laravel 5.2 on the backend ( followed the setup as explained in the docs:

[https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/billing#braintree-configuration]

and i have created a `BraintreeController.php` and it returns the `client token` as `json`. It looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Braintree_ClientToken;
use App\Http\Requests;

class BraintreeController extends Controller
{
    public function token()
    {
        return response()->json(['token' => Braintree_ClientToken::generate() ], 200);
    }
}
```

At this point everything is good.

On client side i have Angularjs set up and here is my `BillingController.js` :

```
$http.get('/braintree/token').then(function(result){
    braintree.setup(result.data.token, "dropin", {
        container: "payment",
        paypal: {
             button: {
                 type: 'checkout'
             }
        }
     });
});

$('#customButton').on('click', function(event) {
      var map = {};
      $('#billForm').find('input').each(function() {
        map[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
      });
      console.log(map);

      $http.post('/order/checkout', map).then(function(result){
          console.log(result);
      });
  });
```

And I have a simple html template `billing.html` containing the form like so:

```
<form id="billForm">
    <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname">
    <input type="text" name="address1" id="address1">
    <input type="text" name="city" id="city">
    <input type="text" name="postalcode" id="postalcode">

    <div id="payment"></div>
    <button id="customButton">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The problem I have is that in `BillingController.js` the logs are showing that the `payment_method_nonse` is "empty" or is "empty string". Does anyone have an idea what i am doing wrong? Thank you.

EDIT:

Just to add and show everyone the method on the receiving end of posted data. Basically i'm posting form data to `/order/checkout` to `OrdersController.php` inside the `store` method. And this is how it looks:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $result = Braintree_Transaction::sale([
       'amount' => '10.00',
       'paymentMethodNonce' => $request->input('payment_method_nonce'),
       'options' => [
           'submitForSettlement' => True
       ]
   ]);

   dd($result);
}
```

And this spits back this:

```
Error {#211
  +success: false
  #_attributes: array:8 [
    "errors" => ErrorCollection {#213
      -_errors: ValidationErrorCollection {#227
        -_errors: []
        -_nested: array:1 [
          "transaction" => ValidationErrorCollection {#214
            -_errors: array:1 [
              0 => Validation {#212
                -_attribute: "base"
                -_code: "91508"
                -_message: "Cannot determine payment method."
              }
            ]
            -_nested: array:1 [
              "creditCard" => ValidationErrorCollection {#216
                -_errors: array:1 [
                  0 => Validation {#217
                    -_attribute: "cvv"
                    -_code: "81706"
                    -_message: "CVV is required."
                  }
                ]
                -_nested: []
                #_collection: []
              }
            ]
            #_collection: []
          }
        ]
        #_collection: []
      }
    }
    "params" => array:1 [
      "transaction" => array:4 [
        "type" => "sale"
        "amount" => "10.00"
        "paymentMethodNonce" => null
        "options" => array:1 [
          "submitForSettlement" => "true"
        ]
      ]
    ]
    "message" => """
      Cannot determine payment method.\n
      CVV is required.
      """
    "creditCardVerification" => null
    "transaction" => null
    "subscription" => null
    "merchantAccount" => null
    "verification" => null
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm that `Braintree_ClientToken::generate()` is correctly retrieving your client token?

Comment: yes. I did a `console.log` inside the ajax call to server to this URI `"/braintree/token"`  in `BillingController.js` on the result, like so: `consoloe.log(result.data)` then eventually retrieved it with `result.data.token` as thats how i configured it inside `BraintreeController.php` on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact our [support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Form data that gets entered into the Drop-in gets nonced when the form's submit button is clicked. Because your form does not have a submit button, no nonce is generated.

You can use the [`onPaymentMethodReceived` callback](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/client-reference/javascript/v2/configuration#setup-method-options) to submit your form's data. When you define this callback, your form will not be submitted, which is the desired behavior you are indicating above.

Here is an example of where to [define your `onPaymentMethodReceived` callback](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/javascript/v2#onpaymentmethodreceived):

```
braintree.setup('CLIENT-TOKEN-FROM-SERVER', 'dropin', {
  container: 'dropin-container',
  onPaymentMethodReceived: function (obj) {
      var map = {};
      $('#billForm').find('input').each(function() {
        map[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
      });
      map['payment_method_nonce'] = obj.nonce;
      console.log(map);

      $http.post('/order/checkout', map).then(function(result){
          console.log(result);
      });
  }
});
```

Keep in mind your form button will need the `type='submit'` attribute to trigger the callback.

If you wish to trigger your form submission while your `onPaymentMethodReceived` callback is defined, you can follow [these instructions](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/client-reference/javascript/v2/best-practices#bypass-submit-handlers) to do so.

Comment: i've added `type='submit'` attribute to the button and move the code into `braintree.setup()` inside `onPaymentMethodReceived` method as you have done here, but when i go to click the button nothing happens, nothing in browser console either.

Comment: I seem to have a succes... I think i have to apologize firstly, it was an oversight on my part. Your way yielded great success. I actually had my button OUTSIDE the form. Bringing it back in then implementing your method got me back on track. So two things: add `submit` attribute and implement `onPaymentMethodReceived` did the trick. Thanks a gazillion!

Answer (score 0):

The payment method nonce field in your form will be empty before the form is submitted. This is expected behavior.

Braintree's javascript will automatically inject the nonce into your form after the form has been submitted and the card information is encrypted into a payment method nonce. Can you confirm that the field is still empty after you submit the form and a payment method nonce is returned successfully?

Comment: yes i can confirm that i'd collected all form input values and submitted the form to the server - look in my `BillingController,js` . I'm also doing a console.log on the json that the server returns. And in my `OrderController.php` on the server i'm invoking `Braintree_Transaction::sale()` passing it the `amount`, `paymentMethodNonce` and setting `submitForSettlement` to true. And finally return the result from this method.  There are a couple of errors there and one of them is `_message: "Cannot determine payment method."`

Comment: got to remember i'm trying to submit form values to server through ajax therefore the form does not necessarily have to be "submitted" per se but Im using `<button>` just to capture values after user has finished filling in details. So what i'm trying to understand is, I'm i interfering with `braintree.js` by doing it this way? do i HAVE to make form "submit" and only then will the `nonce` be generated?